# Skip executing test for the dependency module when running test

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Let's say I am having two modules 'app' and 'library'.

'app' module depends on 'library'. I have written java unit test for both of the modules.
When I run test for 'app' module, Gradle builds the 'library' module and also run the test for 'library' module.

Is there any way that I can skip running 'library' module unit test when running for 'app'.

Answer (score 0):

Try `./gradlew test{productFlavour}{Variant}`

For example to run all unit tests on our CI server. I use `./gradlew testCiDebug`

You could also try gradle's `-x parameter` as described here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:excluding_tasks_from_the_command_line

Then, you should be able to exclude tasks running on other modules.

Moreover, if like me, your included libraries had lint error's which you don't care about. Add this to your app's `build.gradle`

```
  lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
```